# When running Dotnet Publish for nuget in VSTS with local Agent it always try to publish old version why?

Tags: msbuild, nuget, .net-core

I have a strange problem I can't figure out how to solve. 
I use .net core and on VSTS I have this build pipeline:

1... Dotnet restore

2... MsBuild

3... Dotnet test

4... Publish test

5... Dotnet pack

6... Dotnet publish

Everything works fine when running it in VSTS but as soon I choose my own agent it always tries to publish an older version of the package then it did pack in step 4.

I pack for example this one:
C:\agent_work\3\s\JobOffice.Mobile.Infrastructure\src\JobOffice.Mobile.Infrastructure\bin\Release\JobOffice.Mobile.Infrastructure.1.0.6.nupkg

Put it will always try to publish an older one eg:
JobOffice.Mobile.Infrastructure.1.0.2.nupkg

This only happens when using my own local agent not the one in VSTS then it works all the time...

Any clue?

In Nuget publish I use this: ***.nupkg;-:***.symbols.nupkg

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution... 
I added A Delete files step in the start of my build pipeline with the source to my root and then content to delete to:
 ***.nupkg;-:***.symbols.nupkg